# Mockery __call() has a different signature

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit, mockery

I'm using Mockery to mock a class with a `__call()` magic method.

The problem is my mocked object has `__call()` with a different signature to the real class and I get this error:

```
ErrorException: Declaration of Mockery_10_EpiTwitter::__call() should be compatible with EpiTwitter::__call($name, $params = NULL)
```

The following is my mocking procedure:

```
$mock = Mockery::mock('EpiTwitter')->shouldReceive('useAPIVersion')->once()->with('1.1')->mock();
```

I also tried to make a partial mock but the above error still appears.

Answer (score 3):

The error is caused by the E_STRICT error level, that does not allow child methods with different arguments or access level than their parents.

Comment: Spot on! I was able to get around this by putting `if(defined('E_STRICT')) error_reporting('E_ALL ^ E_STRICT')` in the part of test that uses `__call()`